# How can I randomly select a given number of multiple cells in a table with selection criteria?

Tags: excel, random, excel-formula

I have searched far and wide and found answers for a similar 1-dimensional problem (i.e., random selection from a column with criteria), but not for my particular problem (random selection of a specified number of values from a table with criteria).

I am using Excel 2019.

I have a table of values from 0 to 9, example below.
The Nth row specifies the values I want to randomly select from the first N-1 rows of the table, AND the values frequency in the Nth row indicates the number of each value I want to select.

| Col1 | Col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 7 | 3 | 0 |
| 9 | 4 | 5 |
| 1 | 7 | 8 |
| 7 | 3 | 3 |

So for the table shown, you can see 2 instances of the value "3" in the last row, meaning I want to randomly select 2 instances of the value "3" from the first N-1 rows. Similarly I want to select 1 instance of the value "7" from the first N-1 rows.

I have attempted creating an (N-1) x 10 helper table and was going to break the problem into 10 sub-problems of the 1-dimensional variety but just got myself even more lost.

I am open to either formula or VBA based solutions.

Ideally the solution would be a table with the same number of columns and N-1 rows, where cells take the values 0 or 1 indicating the random selection positions like the following.
In this example solution we see two instances of the "3" were selected, one from the first row last column, one from the third row second column; also one instance of the value "7" was selected, from the fifth row second column. There are multiple solutions however considering there are more instances of "3" and "7" to randomly select from.

| Col4 | Col5 | Col6 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |

Alternatively applying formatting (e.g. bold + red) to the randomly selected cells would suffice.

Any help is very much appreciated :)

Comment: In your example result shouldn't there also be `1`'s for 7x `7`? Also, there are not that many `7`'s, should it show `1` for all values found instead (3 in total)?

Comment: Are you using Excel 2016? I'm thinking a formula might be practical with Excel 365 where you've got Sort and Randarray, but maybe VBA with Excel 2016.

Comment: @P.b, no. Because there is only one instance of the value "7" in the last row of the problem table, then only one instance of "7" should be randomly selected from the first N-1 rows.

Comment: @TomSharpe sorry I am using Excel 2019 (corrected the post). I can get access to Office 365 if necessary but VBA is fine (I am less experienced with VBA however). I want to be able to apply the solution to multiple tables, so if I paste in new values in the problem table I can quickly get a new solution without having to do go through too many steps each time (e.g. click a button to run a macro, formula automatically updates).

Comment: @Jess_420 I've sketched out how I would do this in VBA, but haven't had much time to work on it - hopefully will post something in next day or two.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible VBA solution. It uses two classes

*Values*

```
Public count As Integer
Public positionList As Scripting.Dictionary
```

*Positions*

```
Public row As Integer
Public column As Integer
Public selected As Boolean
```

which have to be declared in class modules.

You have to

```
' Select Tools->References from the Visual Basic menu.
' Check box beside "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" in the list.
```

in order to use the dictionary.

The code is

```
Sub randTable()

    Const headers As Integer = 1
    
    Randomize

    Dim area As Variant
    
    area = Selection.value
    
    Dim nrows As Integer
    Dim ncols As Integer
    
    nrows = UBound(area, 1) - LBound(area, 1) + 1
    ncols = UBound(area, 2) - LBound(area, 2) + 1
        
    ' Populate list of unique values in bottom row
    
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim number As Integer
    Dim valueList As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim value As values
    
    For c = 1 To ncols
    
        number = area(nrows, c)
        
        If valueList.Exists(number) Then
            valueList(number).count = valueList(number).count + 1
        Else
            Set value = New values
            valueList.Add number, value
            valueList(number).count = 1
        End If
        
    Next c
     
    ' Populate positions where numbers are found in rows headers+1 to n-1 (row 1 is header)
    
    Dim key As Variant
    Dim positionList As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim position As positions
    Dim matchCounter As Integer
    
    For Each key In valueList
    
        matchCounter = 0
        
        Set positionList = New Scripting.Dictionary
        
        For r = headers + 1 To nrows - 1
        
            For c = 1 To ncols
            
            If area(r, c) = key Then
                Set position = New positions
                position.row = r
                position.column = c
                matchCounter = matchCounter + 1
                positionList.Add matchCounter, position
            End If
            
            Next c
            
        Next r
        
        Set valueList(key).positionList = positionList
        
        If valueList(key).count > positionList.count Then
            MsgBox "Too many repeats"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
            
    Next key
    
    'Select random cells matching bottom row to highlight
    
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim rand As Integer
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim selected As Boolean
    
    ' Loop over distinct values
    
    For i = 0 To valueList.count - 1
    
        Set positionList = valueList.Items(i).positionList
        count = valueList.Items(i).count
        
        'Loop over count per value (number of occurrences of current number in bottom row)
    
        For j = 1 To count
        
            selected = True
            
            ' Try random positions within list of matches until unused position found
            
            Do While selected
            
                rand = Int(Rnd * positionList.count)
                
                selected = positionList.Items(rand).selected
                
                If selected = False Then
                
                    r = positionList.Items(rand).row
                 
                    c = positionList.Items(rand).column
                
                    Selection.Cells(r, c).Interior.ColorIndex = i + 3
                    
                    positionList.Items(rand).selected = True
                    
                End If
            
            Loop
        
        Next j
    
    
    Next i


End Sub
```

Typical result is

[image]

In order to use it, just select the table or range and run the macro. I've assumed that the table or range has headers - if it doesn't change the second line to

```
Const headers As Integer = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the array formula answer using Let in Excel 365. The idea is to build on a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70448428/pick-person-with-most-wins/70451169#70451169) to sort positions (numbered row-wise from 0 to rows X columns -1) in the range by the number at that position and then by a random array. Then filter out only the first n of each group for a given number where n is the number of occurrences of that number in the last row of the range. Finally generate a 2d array the same size and shape as the original range, and set its elements to a 1 where the position number matches the filtered list of positions.

```
=LET(
range,A2:C6,
lastRow,A7:C7,
cells,COUNT(range),
rows,ROWS(range),
cols,COLUMNS(range),
positions,SEQUENCE(cells,1,0),
colNumbers,INDEX(range,positions/cols+1,MOD(positions,cols)+1),
sortPositions,SORTBY(positions,colNumbers,1,RANDARRAY(cells),1),
sortNumbers,SORT(colNumbers),
occurrences,positions-XMATCH(sortNumbers,sortNumbers)+1,
lastRowCounts,COUNTIF(lastRow,lastRow),
countPerNumber,XLOOKUP(sortNumbers,lastRow,lastRowCounts,0),
filteredPositions,FILTER(sortPositions,occurrences<countPerNumber),
IF(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(SEQUENCE(rows,cols,0),filteredPositions)),1,0)
)
```

*Typical result*

[image]